# Combine multiple separate lists into a list of lists

Tags: python, list

Below are three lists which I would like to combine into a single nested list:

```
List_1=[1,2,3]
List_2=[4,5,6]
List_3=[7,8,9]
```

My attempt:

```
List_x=[]
List_x.append(List_1)
List_x.append(List_2)
List_x.append(List_3)
print List_x
```

Result:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Desired result: Same as the result I got, but the approach is extremely slow given the size of my actual data.

Comment: How are you getting `List_1`, `List_2` and `List_3`?

Comment: So you want a lit containing the 3 lists, right? Not a single (flat) list containing all the elements from the lists.

Comment: yes, a single list containing the three lists.

Comment: This should run fast completely independent of how much data is in the lists.

Comment: Is it possible for your data to use numpy arrays instead of lists?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you need a nested list (list of list), Concat them like this:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = [4,5,6]
>>> l3 = [7,8,9]
>>> l123 = [l1,l2,l3]
>>> l123
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

If you want a flattened combined list, use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = [4,5,6]
>>> l3 = [7,8,9]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*[l1,l2,l3]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If memory space is a problem, you can use `append`:

```
>>> l1 = [[1,2,3]]
>>> l1.append([4,5,6])
>>> l1.append([7,8,9])
>>> l1
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

If you want a flattened list and memory is a problem, use `extend`:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l1.extend([4,5,6])
>>> l1.extend([7,8,9])
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Why are the last two code snippets memory saving? I don't see much difference of between the first two and the latter

Answer (score 1):

Adding each list into the nested list is a simple .append() method.  I've used ARGS in the function, this way you can pass as many lists through to the function as you like and you will have to do nothing to change the function itself!

```
list1, list2, list3 = [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3,4], [1, 3, 4, 5]
nested_list =[]

def nest_lists(*argv):
    for arg in argv:
        nested_list.append(arg)
    return nested_list

print(f"Your nested lists are {nest_lists(list1, list2, list3)}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested list:

```
>>> list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list_2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> list_3 = [7, 8, 0]
>>> nested = [list_1, list_2, list_3]
>>> nested
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Merged list:

```
>>> list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list_2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> list_3 = [7, 8, 9]
>>> merged = list_1 + list_2 + list_3
>>> merged
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```